# How to link external qss Stylesheet inside QT designer .ui file

Tags: qt, qt-designer, qtstylesheets

I have downloaded these stylesheets of QT designer: https://github.com/Alexhuszagh/BreezeStyleSheets

And I would like to link the qss file "dark.qss" directly in the .ui file in the QT designer, "Edit Style Sheet" Menu.

The stylesheet has a resource "qrc" file which is recognized by QT designer. And in the "Edit Style Sheet" Menu I see the option to select the dark.qss file. The only problem is I get an error "Invalid Style Sheet" when adding it with url.

I have tried copying the content of dark.qss directly in the "Edit Style Sheet" Menu. And this works. It actually changes the style. But I would prefer to have a link to the qss file instead of the complete code.

Is it possible to link the qss file using the "Edit Style Sheet" Menu?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, You can not. You have to load the file using QFile and load it into app as the README of the repository shows.

Comment: I did it like the readme says...but the problem was after making some updates to the .ui file the changes are gone

Comment: @Mihail-CosminMunteanu I don't understand you, it seems you have an XY problem.